# When/why would one want to kill the IPython kernel?

Tags: ipython, spyder, exit

Background: I am new to Python and Spark.  In Spyder, I was
troubleshooting why the following IPython console Startup command
sometimes leads to multiple Spark Web UIs on ports 4040, 4041,
4042, etc.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession ; spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkExamples.com").getOrCreate()
```

I thought it might have something to do with the Startup command
running again after I issue `exit()`.  Sometimes, I see a message about
reconnecting to a kernel, but not always.

I attempted to banish some of my ignorance by reading about the REPL
and the kernel. At a high level, it seems simple (as with most
things): the kernel interprets the commands from the console.  I know
that `exit()` restarts the kernel, whereas *in Spyder*, `sys.exit()` does
not.

This is how I got to the point of wondering ***why one would want to kill
the kernel.  Under what circumstances would this be done?***
I suspect that this depends on the amount of state carried in the
kernel process.

Can anyone provide a "dummy's" description of the state carried by the
kernel and the circumstances under which one would want to kill it,
i.e., using `exit()` instead of `sys.exit()`

P.S. Regarding the background above, I know that `spark.stop()` is
needed, and I will continue troubleshooting the redundant Web UI.  But
it seems that it's important to know what happens when I issue an
exit command at the console.